# How to Insert php variable directly to database laravel?

Tags: laravel, query-builder

I want to insert my values to database directly using query builder laravel,
but issue is that how to save these data variables to database

```
    public function create(epanelRequest $request)
{
    $applicantName  = Input::get('ApplicantName');
    $applicantEmail = Input::get('ApplicantEmail');
    $applicantPhone = Input::get('ApplicantPhone');
    $applicantCity =  Input::get('ApplicantCity');

    $id = DB::table('epanel')->max('id');
    $insertedId = $id + 1;

    //$xuserName = preg_split('/\s+/', $applicantName);
    //$userName = "ssdhdhjdj";

    DB::table('epanel')->insertGetId([ 'username'=> $userName ,'name' => $applicantName, 'email' => $ApplicantEmail, 'phone' => $applicantPhone, 'counter' => 1, 'city' => $applicantCity, ]);

    return redirect()->back();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have your table setup as a model in Laravel you should be able to initialize a new entry into the table like so:

```
$table_variable = new ModelName;
```

And for each value you could enter it in like so:

```
$table_variable->column = $applicantName;
```

And at the end of your function you can save it by entering `$table_variable->save();`

This is at least how I manage to go it.

Comment: is it possible with query builder only?